# How to stop running selenium tests AFTER webdriver.quit()?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have made a Windows Forms app to host my GUI for running selenium tests.

When the user presses the "run test" button, it launches an instance of chromedriver and runs the selected selenium test.

However, let's say that while the test is running, the user decides they want to stop the test, or simply not have the entire test run.

I have a button on the form that calls FixtureTearDown() in case this were to happen. FixtureTearDown is simply:

```
if (_driver != null) _driver.Quit();
```

However, if you DO press this "stop test" button, the driver closes, but the selenium test keeps executing the script as if the webdriver were still open, which then throws errors (because it can't find elements because the driver is closed, duh) and causes my Windows Forms app to crash.

So, is there a way to gracefully halt the running of a selenium script? Thanks in advance for the help, and i apologize if this is a dumb question, i am still new to selenium and c# in general.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured it out. It's probably not good practice, but it does what I need it to do.

In each test method I set a target thread to the current thread that's about to start

```
Thread targetThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
```

and then, on "stop test" click, end the thread.

```
public void haltScript()
    {
        targetThread.Abort();
    }
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
webDriver.Quit();
```

will **NOT** stop the execution of tests. It will continue until all the tests are done with executing in the class/suit depending on how you have the set up. That part is usually handled by the test runner. Invoke the mechanism used by the test runner to stop the tests execution from the app you have created.

Comment: yes, i know webdriver.quit does not stop the execution of tests. that's why i'm asking the question!! you say "invoke the mechanism used by the test runner to stop the tests", but i have no mechanism. that's what i'm asking, what mechanism can i use to halt the running of the scripts?

Comment: @kdeez As I said it depends on what kind of Test Runner you are using. For example I use RSharper and sometimes NUnit Test runner for my tests. Probably refer to the api doc of the test runner you are using and call the api to stop the execution from the app you have created

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I can suggest.

1) You can set a public "flag" variable, like a Boolean. It will be set to false when you start the test. The button "stop test" will set it to true. As your test is running, it should check whether its value. If true, it will exit the test script.

2) You can set it run on a different thread. The "stop test" will then stop the thread on which the test is running.

You may refer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx on setting it up.

Hope this helps.